# Partially volatile variable?

Tags: c++, optimization, volatile

Suppose I have a micro controller with a main loop and 1 millisecond interrupt (if you don't know what that is it is just a task that interrupts the main loop's execution, while it does something.....and it is a 1 millisecond interrupt, because it happens every millisecond).

I have a variable that I use to communicate between the main loop and the millisecond interrupt:

```
volatile status_t Status;
```

Right now I have a section of code in the main loop that updates the `Status` variable, which does a ton of transformations on it:

```
cli();    // This temporarily turns off interrupts, so we don't 
          // modify the variable unsafely
Status.UpdateStuff();
Status.UpdateOtherStuff();
//etc.

sei();    // Turn interrupts back on
```

The problem is that each of these function calls to `Status` rewrites `Status`......the compiler can not cache the values of Status in local memory.

One possible solution to this problem is this:

```
cli();
status_t* localStatus = (status_t*)&Status;
localStatus->UpdateStuff();
localStatus->UpdateOtherStuff();
//etc.

Status = *localStatus;
sei();
```

The real question here is this:

Is this going to do what I hope it will do or is there a better way to get around the issue of constant refreshing the variable, instead of allowing the optimizer to cache the variable?

Comment: In the second snippet I suppose you mean `&Status`. BTW, I don't think there are much better alternatives.

Comment: Have the timer insert jobs in a queue and the main thread read the queue and process the jobs.  You only need a mutex on the queue operations.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yup, that is what I meant...

Comment: Don't know it that works, but you can try to declare your status variable as ordinary, and access it through a "volatilized" pointer when you feel like it `*(volatile status_t*)&Status`. Anyway, Barmar's answer is a better one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second version might still write to the microcontroller multiple times, because the compiler may not realize it can cache the value across method calls (it could probably only determine this if the methods are inline). So I suggest making an explicit local copy, not just a local pointer.

```
cli();
status_t localStatus = Status;
localStatus.UpdateStuff();
localStatus.UpdateOtherStuff();
...
Status = localStatus;
sei();
```

Comment: Using this approach you can potentially reduce the span of code that has to run with interrupts disabled to just the code that moves the new version of the status into the shared location.

Answer (score 0):

An example to minimize how much time the processor runs with interrupts disabled. This only works if `nextStatus` doesn't have other side effects. If it did those would have to be recorded and executed once Status has be successfully committed.

```
cli();
do {
  auto lastStatus = Status;
  sei ();

  auto nextStatus = lastStatus;
  nextStatus.UpdateStuff();
  nextStatus.UpdateOtherStuff();
  ...

  cli ();
} while (lastStatus != Status);
Status = nextStatus;
sei();
```